# Why AIC for log-linear model in glm returns Inf?

Tags: r, aic, poisson-regression, log-linear

I am trying to calculate the AIC for log-linear model in R, but i get `Inf` as a result. The model aim is to predict sales in euros based on some variables.

As far as I understand by specifying `poisson(link = log)` in `glm` it changes calcultting method from LSM to maximizing likelihood and assumes different distribution (Poisson insted of normal). But why can't it calculate AIC?

In example below in model 2, where I make log-linear model manually i get AIC (i guess the assumed distribution is normal), but in model 3 AIC is calculated as `Inf`. What is the difference between approaches and which one is correct?

Sample code:

```
    d <- data.frame(x = runif(100, 1, 10))
    d$y = d$x + runif(100, 1, 10)

#linear model
    M1 <- glm(y ~ ., data = d)
    summary(M1)
    AIC(M1)
#-6510.043
#log-linear model
    M2 <- glm(log(y) ~ ., data = d)
    summary(M2)
    AIC(M2)
#-392.0618
#log-linear model
    M3 <- glm(y ~ ., data = d,  poisson(link = log))
    summary(M3)
    AIC(M3)
#Inf
```

Comment: The models M2 and M3 are not the same model with an only different implementation. The`Inf` may come from the wrong family according to the type of variable you used. The variable `x` it seems to be continuous, while the Poisson distribution is a discrete distribution, thus it take only a set of natural numbers. 

Please read about link-function in Generalized Linear Models. I am unable to clearly explain you a mathematic behind this idea, you should do it by yourself:
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-87458-6_9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AIC is defined as $$2k - 2\ln L(\theta)$$ where $k$ is the number of parameters and L is the likelihood of your model. The Poisson distribution assumes that you observe a non-negative whole number, so it doesn't really make sense to use a Poisson `glm` when `y` clearly is not an integer. If you try to evaluate the Poisson density in R, it will return 0 if you give in a decimal number, for example

```
dpois(12.5, lambda = 12)
[1] 0
Warning message:
In dpois(12.5, 12) : non-integer x = 12.500000
```

So if the likelihood is evaluated to 0 then the log-likelihood will evaluate to negative infinity and the AIC will be infinity.

If you on the other hand round the `y` variable to the closest whole number, the AIC value makes more sense:

```
d$y = round(d$y)
M3 <- glm(y ~ ., data = d,  poisson(link = log))
AIC(M3)
480.91
```